# Click functionality on step indicator

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I am trying to give a click functionality to my step indicator. Currently I am using this library from GitHub, https://github.com/badoualy/stepper-indicator.

I saw this library with the click functionality,
https://github.com/kofigyan/StateProgressBar
But this has only steps until 5.

```
<com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar.StateProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/your_state_progress_bar_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:spb_currentStateNumber="one"
        app:spb_maxStateNumber="five"
        app:spb_stateBackgroundColor="#BDBDBD"
        app:spb_stateForegroundColor="#009688"
        app:spb_stateNumberBackgroundColor="#808080"
        app:spb_stateNumberForegroundColor="#eeeeee"
        app:spb_currentStateDescriptionColor="#009688"
        app:spb_stateDescriptionColor="#808080"
        app:spb_animateToCurrentProgressState="true"
        app:spb_checkStateCompleted="true"/>
```

more than 5, is not supported.

Is there any library that really supports this or you have any idea that how can this be implemented?
I want to go to that viewpager when a state is clicked.

Comment: The design is different, so it might not suit your needs, but I have a library to create stepper forms that could be of your interest: https://github.com/ernestoyaquello/VerticalStepperForm (it includes the click functionality, and you can add as many steps as you want).

Comment: @JulioE.RodríguezCabañas I have seen this library, does this have a horizontal version?

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not.

Comment: Any other  libraries or any idea how can I implement this manually with a library?

Comment: I am afraid that there isn't any solution already implemented that I know of, sorry. If I were you, I would probably fork the library that were the closest to my idea and I would modify it to make it suit my requirements.

Comment: I am not an expert.

Comment: If you don't think you can implement it yourself, then you will probably have to settle for one of the available libraries and adapt to it by doing some sacrifices. As I said, I don't know any library that suits your requirements perfectly, but maybe there is one. Good luck!